# pymongo authentication user credentials

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, restful-authentication

i am new to MongoDB and RestFul web services.from the below code i am getting the result from my local server.

```
import pymongo
conn=pymongo.MongoClient()
db = conn['restaurant']      # DB Name.

@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET'])
def getAllRestaurants(request):
    rests = []
    coll = db['Restaurants']            # Collection Name.
    if request.method == 'GET':
        all = coll.find({"isActive":True})
        for each in all:
            json_data = ({"_id":str(each['_id']),'name': each['name']})
            rests.append(json_data)
        data = {"allRestaurants": rests}
        return JSONResponse(data)

GET - http://127.0.0.1:8000/restaurant/getAllRestaurants/
```

> {   "allRestaurants": [
>       {
>         "_id": "579b032ee4b048c9b19d887c",
>         "name": "xxxxx"
>       },
>       {
>         "_id": "579b032ee4b048c9b19d887d",
>         "name": "yyyyy"
>       }   ] }

Up to here its fine.

when i try to connect remote server its giving the authentication error.
i know the username and password.But i dont know how to use and where to use in pymongo module.
my remote server also have same db name and collections.

suppose my **login:test** and **password:test** then how to connect to remote server with pymongo module.
Please correct me if i am wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.authenticate('test', 'test')
```

See also [pymongos documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.authenticate)